# отобразить IPv6-адрес

Tags: c++, winsock

Если с помощью функции `HOSTENT* gethostbyname(const char* name)` я получил структуру с адресами типа IPv6, как мне отобразить их с помощью структуры `in6_addr`?

Comment: вот здесь парень рассказывает про это  http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/86649/#msg464988

Comment: @zergon321, просто интересно: почему отдали предпочтение `in6_addr`, а не `SOCKADDR_IN6` ?

Comment: @isnullxbh, структурная переменная типа `in6_addr` как раз является членом структуры `sockaddr_in6`. Просто я сначала хотел разобраться с выводом самого адреса, а уже потом юзать `sockaddr_in6` в самих приложениях.